# d3js graph code showing y axes in different order for different data

Tags: javascript, canvas, graph, svg, d3.js

Here is my d3js code

```
function ShowGraph(data) {
d3.selectAll('.axis').remove();
var vis = d3.select("#visualisation"),
    WIDTH = 500,
    HEIGHT = 500,
    MARGINS = {
        top: 20,
        right: 20,
        bottom: 20,
        left: 30
    },
    xRange = d3.scale.linear().range([MARGINS.left, WIDTH - MARGINS.right]).domain([d3.min(data, function (d) {
        return d.year;
    }),
    d3.max(data, function (d) {
        return d.year;
    })]),
    yRange = d3.scale.linear().range([HEIGHT - MARGINS.top, MARGINS.bottom]).domain([d3.min(data, function (d) {
        return d.count;
    }),
    d3.max(data, function (d) {
        return d.count;
    })]),
    xAxis = d3.svg.axis() // generate an axis
    .scale(xRange) // set the range of the axis
    .tickSize(5) // height of the ticks
    .tickSubdivide(true), // display ticks between text labels
    yAxis = d3.svg.axis() // generate an axis
    .scale(yRange) // set the range of the axis
    .tickSize(5) // width of the ticks
    .orient("left") // have the text labels on the left hand side
    .tickSubdivide(true); // display ticks between text labels
var transition = vis.transition().duration(1000).ease("exp-in-out");

transition.select(".x.axis").call(xAxis);
transition.select(".y.axis").call(yAxis);




vis.append("svg:g") // add a container for the axis
.attr("class", "x axis") // add some classes so we can style it
.attr("transform", "translate(0," + (HEIGHT - MARGINS.bottom) + ")") // move it into position
.call(xAxis); // finally, add the axis to the visualisation

vis.append("svg:g")
    .attr("class", "y axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + (MARGINS.left) + ",0)")
    .call(yAxis);


var circles = vis.selectAll("circle").data(data)
circles.enter()
    .append("svg:circle")
    .attr("cx", function (d) {
    return xRange(d.year);
})
    .attr("cy", function (d) {
    return yRange(d.count);
})
    .style("fill", "red")

circles.transition().duration(1000)
    .attr("cx", function (d) {
    return xRange(d.year);
})
    .attr("cy", function (d) {
    return yRange(d.count);
})
    .attr("r", 10)

circles.exit()
    .transition().duration(1000)
    .attr("r", 10)
    .remove();

}
```

When the data used is

```
   [{"count": "202", "year": "1590"},
 {"count": "215", "year": "1592"},
 {"count": "179", "year": "1593"},
 {"count": "199", "year": "1594"},
 {"count": "134", "year": "1595"},
 {"count": "176", "year": "1596"},
 {"count": "172", "year": "1597"},
 {"count": "161", "year": "1598"},
 {"count": "199", "year": "1599"},
 {"count": "181", "year": "1600"},
 {"count": "157", "year": "1602"},
 {"count": "179", "year": "1603"},
 {"count": "150", "year": "1606"},
 {"count": "187", "year": "1607"},
 {"count": "133", "year": "1608"},
 {"count": "190", "year": "1609"},
 {"count": "175", "year": "1610"},
 {"count": "91", "year": "1611"},
 {"count": "150", "year": "1612"}
]
```

the y axis of the graph is as shown below(in asc order from top to bottom)
[image]

When the data used is

```
    [{"count": "841", "year": "1590"},
 {"count": "848", "year": "1592"},
 {"count": "579", "year": "1593"},
 {"count": "753", "year": "1594"},
 {"count": "612", "year": "1595"},
 {"count": "740", "year": "1596"},
 {"count": "762", "year": "1597"},
 {"count": "894", "year": "1598"},
 {"count": "937", "year": "1599"},
 {"count": "995", "year": "1600"},
 {"count": "715", "year": "1602"},
 {"count": "786", "year": "1603"},
 {"count": "680", "year": "1606"},
 {"count": "942", "year": "1607"},
 {"count": "525", "year": "1608"},
 {"count": "779", "year": "1609"},
 {"count": "717", "year": "1610"},
 {"count": "421", "year": "1611"},
 {"count": "738", "year": "1612"}
]
```

the y axis of the graph is as shown below(in asc order from bottom to top)
[image]

Can anyone point me out what may be the reason and how to correct this behaviour.
***update***

another test data sample

```
[{"count": "357", "year": "1608"},
            {"count": "375", "year": "1611"},
            {"count": "506", "year": "1606"},
            {"count": "535", "year": "1610"},
            {"count": "551", "year": "1612"},
            {"count": "660", "year": "1597"},
            {"count": "679", "year": "1594"},
            {"count": "689", "year": "1598"},
            {"count": "873", "year": "1595"},
            {"count": "891", "year": "1592"},
            {"count": "990", "year": "1607"},
            {"count": "1031", "year": "1593"},
            {"count": "1038", "year": "1602"},
            {"count": "1064", "year": "1609"},
            {"count": "1264", "year": "1600"},
            {"count": "1357", "year": "1596"},
            {"count": "1616", "year": "1590"},
            {"count": "2299", "year": "1599"},
            {"count": "2559", "year": "1603"}]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you notice when rendering the first set of data, the **y-axis** doesn't look quite right. According the data the min `count` is `91` and max is `215`, but the **y-axis** has `130` as the max.

This is because when building the scales and computing min and max, the values are compared as strings.

To fix it you need to either modify your data arrays to have numeric values where needed

```
[{ "count": 202, "year": 1590},
 { "count": 215, "year": 1592} /*....*/]
```

Or parse them into integers with `parseInt` when building the scales - and don't forget to pass the radix to `parseInt`.

If choosing the later, just modify your scales to this:

```
        /*....*/},
        xRange = d3.scale
                   .linear()
                   .domain([
                      d3.min(data, function(d){ return parseInt(d.year, 10);}),
                      d3.max(data, function(d){ return parseInt(d.year, 10);})
                    ])
                   .range([MARGINS.left, WIDTH - MARGINS.right]),
        yRange = d3.scale
                   .linear()
                   .domain([
                      d3.min(data, function(d){ return parseInt(d.count, 10);}),
                      d3.max(data, function(d){ return parseInt(d.count, 10);})
                    ])
                   .range([HEIGHT - MARGINS.top, MARGINS.bottom]),
```

Here's the JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jaimem/RPGPL/2/

Comment: Please note the d3.extend function: d3.extent(data, function(d) { return parseInt(d.year, 10); }) This function combines the d3.min and d3.max